# Use java agent with manipulated java bytecode (ASM)

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to figure out how [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io) works, with the help of [A Guide to Java Bytecode Manipulation with ASM](https://www.baeldung.com/java-asm). I followed the tutorial and created an 'extra' static field for the Integer class. Here is the simplified logic of the  Instrumentation class:

```
public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
  inst.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, final byte[] buffer) {
      if (className.equals("ClassX")) {
        var reader = new ClassReader(bytes);
        var writer = new ClassWriter(reader, 0);
        var visitor = new ClassVisitor() { // simplified
          @Override
          public void visitEnd() {
            if (!isFieldPresent) {
              var fv = cv.visitField(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_STATIC, "aNewBooleanField", BOOLEAN_TYPE.toString(), null, true);
              if (fv != null) fv.visitEnd();
            }
            cv.visitEnd();
          }
        };
        reader.accept(visitor, 0);
        return writer.toByteArray();
      }
      return buffer;
    }
  });
}
```

I packaged the ASM code with maven; now I am trying the run it, but I got no clue how to use it. I expected I should be able to to something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ClassX.aNewBooleanField);
}
```

This won't compile of course, as the compiler is not aware of the extra field. I tried adding the java agent¹ as the tutorial suggest, but I don't understand that either. How can the compiler be aware of a process (the agent) that operates at runtime?

So bottom line question would be, how do I use the ASM manipulated code?

---

¹ `-javaagent:"/<path>/.m2/repository/org/example/try-asm/1.0-SNAPSHOT/try-asm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"`

Comment: You run the transformation on the dependency, creating a new jar file, which can be used to compile against. Still a bad idea to rely on an agent to run stuff.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Sure, but this whole exercise is just for educational purposes. I won't use stuff like java agents for production code :P. Even reflection code should be used as minimum as possible imho.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the question, the compiler is indeed not aware of the modifications made to the bytecode of the class. Therefore, you can't call `ClassX.aNewBooleanField` directly. Thus you need to fall back to reflection:

```
var modifiedClass = Class.forName("ClassX");
var field = modifiedClass.getField("aNewBooleanField");
System.out.println(field.getBoolean(null));
```

As you can compile your code now, you can run it with the java agent and above code will print out the `true` value!